# export a video from Blender with alpha channel

Tags: after-effects, premiere, blender, alpha

I have a problem exporting a video from Blender (Cycles Render) with Alpha Channel. Generally it's a scene with sailplane flying about a camera positioned near to the floor. In addition to this it is a camera with a fisheye lens, but I don't think this changes anything.
I failed to export the video with alpha in blender, so I exported the 500 frames to pngs with an alpha channel.
I tried many things, but did the job by now.
The target system is Digital Sky 2.

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you've forgot to enable *Transparent* option in the *Film* Panel: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5164/3710

Comment: Or do you just wanna compile/encode your Image sequence?